# JSON data file full of Unicode emoticons rendered with Jekyll results in parsing error

Tags: ruby, json, unicode, jekyll, liquid

I have a really long JSON file, that has lots of unicode in it, most of them are emoticons, like: `\ud83d\ude03` for "smiling face with open mouth", etc... I'm trying to render them on an `index.html` file. JSON file is stored in `_data` folder as expected.

When running `jekyll serve` I encounter this error message:

```
found invalid Unicode character escape code while parsing a quoted scalar at line 1408 column 17
```

I don't know if it is a problem of ruby, the liquid template engine, or jekyll, or something else...

Is it possible to force it to skip these parts, where emoticons are involved?

Or - even better - to display them in the browser?

Comment: Can you confirm whether it's truly ANY unicode sequence or just the one referenced (line 1408 column 17)?

Comment: yes, if I correct this one, it jumps to the next occurence.

Comment: Roger that, what happens if in your index.html, where you are rendering each entry, if you pipe them through the `escape` filter?

Comment: It is the same error with the escape filter. 

I thought JSON is only parsed when it is referenced somewhere in `index.html` or other template files, but turns out if I just drop the JSON file on the fly into the `_data` folder without a reference to it from `index.html`, the console instantly gives me that error message. Maybe it's normal, I just thought it works the other way around.

Comment: Do you have a github repository ?

Comment: Thank you for your help! I can't share the data, I just thought it would the nice to do it with Jekyll, since it can deal with JSON and I'm already familiar with Jekyll. But I had to move on, Handlebar.js worked like a charm.